# Ionic Could not find support-vector-drawable.aar

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic3

Having a weird issue on my Ionic app, I was able to build just fine yesterday but on one build it downloaded a bunch of files like it does when building android and then I got the following error:

> Could not find support-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-vector-drawable/27.1.1/support-vector-drawable-27.1.1.aar

When following the link `https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-vector-drawable/27.1.1/support-vector-drawable-27.1.1.aar` the page has the following JSON:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 404,
      "message": "Could not find resource"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Glad to know I'm not the only one.  This happened to me too.

I've had to use the `cordova-android-support-gradle-release` plugin in the past to handle conflicts with different plugins leveraging different versions of the android support libraries.  I had been using this cordova plugin with version `27.+`.  Changing that to force version `27.1.0` got things building again for me.  (A command to add that plugin is below).

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release  --variable ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=27.1.0
```

Obviously it would be nice to know why this 27.1.1 file went missing today, which would allow continuing to use 27.+.  However, hopefully this gets you running again.

**----2/6/2019 Update:----**

This issue was resolved in my project for the past 4 months.  Then today it came back.  For some reason the `cordova-android-support-gradle-release` .gradle file wasn't getting added to the build (even though others were).  I followed the answer from @Moofish, and removed/re-installed the plugin (at 27.1.0 again).  Then builds started working again.  For me this did upgrade the `cordova-android-support-gradle-release` plugin from `@1.4.4` to `@2.0.1`.  Not sure if that was a fluke or a predictable thing.

Comment: That would get added to the config.xml by installing the plugin.  I edited the answer for clarity.  Try the command above.  If you are using ionic, obviously  you could prefix the command with `ionic`, similar to other plugin install commands.

Comment: You may want to purge the plugins directory, remove the platform, then re-add the platform.  Not sure if this plugin would retroactively fix things already installed. Or peek at the docs to make sure you are installing it properly for your setup.  There's obviously also a chance this doesn't fix what you're running into, but it fixed it for me (and mine broke this AM too).  https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I already installed the plugin of cordova-android-support-gradle-release, so I removed the plugin (`ionic cordova plugin rmcordova-android-support-gradle-release`) and installed again the plugin (`cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release  --variable ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=27.1.0`), emmm...and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I will leave a different solution from [BRass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6599076/brass)' in case you don't want to play around with your plugins or Android support versions.

We had the exact same errors when trying to build our app and solved it by adding a script hook on `after_platform_add` to re-order the repository list in `build.gradle` file so the project looks for the .aar in a different place.

```
// Add <hook src="path/to/after_platform_add.js" type="after_platform_add" /> to your config.xml

var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(ctx) {
    var gradlePath = './platforms/android/build.gradle';
    var gradleFile = fs.readFileSync(gradlePath, 'ascii');
    if (ctx.opts.platforms[0].indexOf('android') !== -1) {
        gradleArray = gradleFile.split('\n');
        for (var i = 0; i < gradleArray.length; i++) {
            if (gradleArray[i].includes('jcenter()') && gradleArray[i + 1].includes('maven')) {
                var jcenter = gradleArray.splice(i, 1)[0];
                gradleArray.splice(i + 3, 0, jcenter);
            }
        }
        gradleFile = gradleArray.join('\n');
        fs.writeFileSync(gradlePath, gradleFile);
        console.log('Reordered repositories');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the build.gradle in platforms and in app/build.gradle to:

```
{
        mavenCentral()
        google() // Add this
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Down side here is for cordova apps, the build.gradle file is generated by cordova.  It will get stepped on at various points (and it is typically not under source control).